# Assigning a border to each cell of the first column of a table

Tags: jquery

Is this the proper way to assign a border to a cell for the first column in the table?

```
$(gridContentTable).find("tbody tr td[cellIndex=" + (frozenColCount - 1) + "]").css("border-right", freezeColStyle);
```

Edit: More info:

This works for the first cell in the header:

```
$(tableHeaderCol).eq((frozenColCount - 1)).css("border-right", freezeColStyle);
```

I'm defining the variables with this:

```
function getGridInfo() {
    gridHeaderTable = grid.find(".t-grid-header table");
    gridContentTable = grid.find(".t-grid-content table");
    tableHeaderGroupCol = $(gridHeaderTable).find("colGroup col");
    tableHeaderCol = $(gridHeaderTable).find("tbody tr th");
    tableContentGroupCol = $(gridContentTable).find("colGroup col");
    totalColCount = $(tableHeaderGroupCol).length;
}
```

Only the header has the CSS applied, the content of the table does not. And this will ultimately do the first cell of each row in the first column.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us more information? Does it even work?

Comment: _Is this the proper way_ - **no**. And it looks like you want each COLUMN, not ROW...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(gridContentTable).find("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (frozenColCount - 1) + ")").css("border-right", freezeColStyle);
```

":eq" gives you the nth element in the set. ":nth-child" gives you each nth child in the set.

http://jsfiddle.net/5BmGU/

Comment: Tried this one, same result. Thanks.

Comment: I think the code is missing the 'n'. To do every third for example, it's 3n, not just 3.

Comment: Yes flem, that was what I was after. Thanks for the assistance.